# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: >org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.SharedContext: method <init>()V not found

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to generate a pdf from an html file.when I run my code from eclipse everything works fine and the pdf is created successfully.However when I create the jar file and run it,at the moment of creating the pdf I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.xhtmlrenderer.la
yout.SharedContext: method <init>()V not found
at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:107)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:98)
```

Anyone has an idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

¿How are you generating the jar?

Ensure you are using the same flyingsaucer-renderer.jar version when run from eclipse and when run the jar. If you are using maven is possible that have been generated duplicated dependencies.

Comment: well I am using eclipse,to generate my jar file. I  do a  right click then  export->runnable JAR->Finish..I choose "exctract required libraries into generated JAR as the library handling option.as for the version,the appear to be the same to me

Comment: Extract SharedContext.class from the jar and decompile it. It looks like the class inside your jar doesn't have a default constructor. If you don't instantiate this class inside your code there will be another library doing it. You must ensure that all the libraries inside your jar are the same that the libraries used by eclipse. Differents libraries or different versions can cause these incompatibilities.